# How to use "onSuccess" in useQuery in tRPC v10?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, trpc.io, t3

I am checking out trpc with t3 stack and I want to update a state when useQuery is successful.

and I am getting typescript error on the frontend,

> Argument of type '{ onSuccess: (shoppingList: ShoppingItem[]) => void; }' is not assignable to >parameter of type 'void'.

I am doing something like this on my frontend,

```
const [items, setItems] = useState<ShoppingItem[]>([]);
  const { data: itemsData, isLoading } = trpc.item.getItem.useQuery({
    onSuccess: (shoppingList) => {
      setItems(shoppingList);
    },
  });
```

this is my backend route,

```
getItem: publicProcedure.query(async ({ ctx }) => {
    const items = await ctx.prisma.shoppingItem.findMany();
    return items;
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

In React Query v4 `onSuccess` is depricated. (as stated in @tanstack/react-query
[documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/useQuery#:%7E:text=onSuccess%3A%20(data%3A%20TData,next%20major%20version))

The best thing to do now is to use `useEffect` where the `data` is a dependency.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setItems(itemsData)
}, [itemsData]);
```

More context for this change and why the `onSuccess` pattern is problematic can be found in a blog post from the creator here:
https://tkdodo.eu/blog/breaking-react-querys-api-on-purpose

Comment: I understand this is not the solution to your problem per se, but it is important to know not to use `onSuccess`, `onError` since they will not be available in future versions.

Answer (score 3):

I guesse it can be a solution

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState<ShoppingItem[]>([]);   const {
 data: itemsData, isLoading } = trpc.item.getItem.useQuery(undefined ,
 { onSuccess: (shoppingList) => {setItems(shoppingList)} 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a parameter in your useQuery, you need to pass an array as your first parameter which will be the query key. So it could look something like this -

```
const [items, setItems] = useState<ShoppingItem[]>([]);
  const { data: itemsData, isLoading } = trpc.item.getItem.useQuery(['some-key'], {
    onSuccess: (shoppingList) => {
      setItems(shoppingList);
    },
  });
```